# 5 Second Wait between webkit mask position animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-animations, css-mask

I'm working on a CSS shining effects on the icons so far I have created the effect using webkit mask below is my snippet

```
 .hm-instagram:before{
 color: #0ED8F6;

  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(-75deg, rgba(14,216,246,.6) 30%, #0ED8F6 50%, rgba(14,216,246,.6) 70%);
  -webkit-mask-size: 200%;
animation: shine 2.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes shine {
  from { -webkit-mask-position: 150%; }
  to { -webkit-mask-position: -50%; }
}
```

but now I want this animation to repeat every 5 seconds, like a 5-second delay between each animation loop. I'm not sure how I can achieve this effect using javascript.
any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might just don't need javascript here. You can do this this by css only.

here is how you can do this. instead of counting one animation duration as just animation duration we can count it as animation duration + delay between animations i.e. here we can set the animation duration to 2.5(animation) + 5(delay) = 7.5 seconds.

Then you can change the animation to run for only first 2.5 seconds accordingly. here you can animate from 0% to 33%(33% of 7.5 is 2.5).

example for your css

```css
 .hm-instagram:before{
 color: #0ED8F6;

  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(-75deg, rgba(14,216,246,.6) 30%, #0ED8F6 50%, rgba(14,216,246,.6) 70%);
  -webkit-mask-size: 200%;
animation: shine 7.5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes shine {
  0% { -webkit-mask-position: 150%; }
  33% { -webkit-mask-position: -50%; }
  100% { -webkit-mask-position: -50%; }
}
```

#### JavaScript version

You can use `setInterval` function to toggle the class list of element every 5 second and set your css accordingly.